# Как оптимизировать google карту?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]У меня карта внизу страницы, но сильно ее тормозит на speed page это видно, как сделать так, чтобы при загрузке страницы карта не грузилась, а начинала грузиться например только тогда, когда до нее доскролили вниз?

Comment: по speed page карта процентов 30% загрузки потребляет. попробуйте перенести скрипты вниз страницы. возможно визуально это создаст эффект мгновенного открытия страницы.

Comment: скрипты у меня всегда внизу страницы)